# Retrieving FbxObject3D from an FbxAnimCurveNode

Tags: c++, 3d, maya, fbx

Maya exports all animations to a single FbxAnimStack and FbxAnimLayer. My scene has several objects with independent animations, grouped by top-level objects:

- Object_1

  - this_is_animated_1
  - this_is_animated_2
- Object_2

  - this_is_animated_3
  - this_is_animated_4

I'd like to split the single FbxAnimLayer in several layers, one for each Object. My plan is to walk through all FbxAnimCurveNode, get the targeted property, retrieve the FbxObject3D it belongs to, find the top level FbxObject3D and add those curve to the relevant new FbxAnimLayer.

However, I'm stuck: how do I get the targeted property from an animation curve ? FbxAnimCurveNode::GetChannel is private...

```
for (int i = 0; i < scene->GetSrcObjectCount<FbxAnimCurveNode>() ; ++i) {
    auto curve = scene->GetSrcObject<FbxAnimCurveNode>(i);
    // Stuck ! How to retrieve the targeted
}
```

Or maybe my entire approach is wrong ?